# Ng-repeat not updating array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

As the title says, I have a problem with reference switching. 
My html:

```
div ng-repeat="data in parseurl">
{{data.url}}
</div>
```

In my JS code, I'm trying to do two things. The first step is to grab the data off a server and put it into an array (called allsongs). Afterwards, I parse the data and put it into another array (parseurl).

```
var app = angular.module("write", []);  
app.controller("Ctrl",  ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.allsongs = [];
    $scope.parseurl = [];
    $scope.getstuff = function(){
            $http.get("my link here").then(function(response){
               $scope.allsongs = response.data; 
                }); //step one -> this works!

    $scope.parser(); //step two
    };

   $scope.parser = function()
    {
    for(i=0;i<$scope.allsongs.length;i++) {
    for(var key in $scope.allsongs[i]) {
        var value = $scope.allsongs[i][key];
        var object = {Url : value.Url}; //this does contain the correct info I want
        $scope.parseurl.push(object); 
    }

$scope.getstuff();
}]);
```

So what is happening is that, if I ng-repeat on allsongs, then I do get a bunch of un-parsed urls. But if I ng-repeat on parseurl, then I get nothing. Obviously the reference isn't changing, but how can I do it?

Comment: Did you do `console.log($scope.parseurl)` and check ?

Comment: I put a breakpoint at var object, to check to see if the data was valid. I assume pushing the object into parseurl would update the array

Comment: There are duplicates, and then there are zillion-plicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.parser()` needs to be called after the data was recived. Put it into your promise callback function like in the following example. Please note that `$http` is an asynchronous function. In that way `$scope.parser()` was executed before your request has been finished.

```
$scope.getstuff = function(){
    $http.get("my link here").then(function(response){
        $scope.allsongs = response.data;
        $scope.parser();
    });
};
```